# Jquery .fadein affects containers before

Tags: jquery

I have a mysterious problem:

```
<div class="ttbl0" id="msg0">Messages</div>
```

```js
$(data).hide().fadeIn(1000).insertAfter("#msg0");
```

`data` in this case are:

```
<div class="kld0">
    <div class="mbx24">
        <div class="wlls-t">
            <div class="row1">test1</div>
            <div class="row2">test2</div>
            <div class="row3">test3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine and inserts `data` after `msg0` container with `fadeIn` effect. The problem is that after `data` finishes fading in, the container `msg0` do the same - it disappears and appears again with `fadein` effect.

I tried it with `append` function but have the same problem - container `msg0` disappears and fades in. There are no unclosed tags that may cause this problem.

It happens not only with one container. If I create more:

```
<div class="ttbl0" id="msg0">Messages</div>
<div class="ttbl0">Messages</div>
<div class="ttbl0">Messages</div>
<div class="ttbl0">Messages</div>
```

all of them disappear and fade in.

```
.ttbl0 { 
    width: 759px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-right: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}




$(document.body).on('submit','#sendmessage',function() {

var str = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/send.php",
data: str,
success: function(data) {


$(data).hide().fadeIn(1000).insertAfter("#msg0");

}

});
return false;
});
```

Comment: What is `data` specifically? A string of HTML, or a jQuery object? A working example would help a lot here

Answer (score 0):

Container ttbl0 had `float:left` That was the problem. I changed:

```
float:left
```

to

```
display:inline-block
```

and the problem is gone.

And a message to people who watch new posts to rate them down: if you continue in this way, your website will lose visitors. It's really humilating to get negative ratings instead of problem solutions.